# Get the row number where Exception occured

Tags: apex, visualforce, validation, exception

I got a VF page where a user can enter many contacts and save them all in one go. I got a validation on Email field to stop the user entering duplicate values when saving records.

Therefore to catch the exception I use ex.getMessage(); where it shows in which row the duplicate value occurred for the Email.

Exception-----when using ex.getMessage

Error:
Insert failed. First exception on row 0; first error: DUPLICATES_DETECTED, Email address already exists on another valid contact record. We recommend you use the existing record(s) instead.: []

But I want to use a custom message instead to provide a meaningful message and want to display the row number as well for the user to understand in which row the exception occurred. Help on this is much appreciated !

Controller Method

```
public PageReference SaveMultipleContacts(){
        try{
            AddMultipleContactsHelper.save(contList);
            ApexPages.AddMessage(new ApexPages.Message(ApexPages.Severity.CONFIRM, Label.Save_multiple_contacts_success));
            saved =true;

        }catch(Exception ex){
            ApexPages.addMessage(new Apexpages.Message(Apexpages.Severity.ERROR,ex.getMessage()));
            saved =false;
        }
        return null;
    }
```

Comment: Have you looked at getStackTraceString?

Comment: DmlException EX1 = (DmlException)ex;
 for(Integer i = 0 ; i<ex1.getNumDml(); i++){
     ApexPages.addMessage(new Apexpages.Message(Apexpages.Severity.ERROR,'Email Address on row' +' '+(EX1.getDmlIndex(i)+1)+' '+'already exists in another valid Contact record. Please use a unique Email Address' ));

Comment: above solution worked !

Answer (score 1):

Following solution worked !

```
DmlException EX1 = (DmlException)ex;
    for(Integer i = 0 ; i<ex1.getNumDml(); i++){
        ApexPages.addMessage(new Apexpages.Message(Apexpages.Severity.ERROR,'Email Address on row' +' '+(EX1.getDmlIndex(i)+1)+' '+'already exists in another valid Contact record. Please use a unique Email Address' ));
```